# C# code to access users' maibox through app-only authentication (using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices)

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Since Microsoft prevents basic authentication, i have to rebuild my app that goes and downloads all attachments matching specific criteria from a mailbox in O365. I would like to implement it by using app-only authentication method using tokens

My application is registered in AD and all permissions that i could think of have been added and granted by global admin.

I have setup and added appID, clientSecret,tenantID etc.

this is my current code can someone guide me how to do

```
            exch.ExchangeService exchange = null;
            string Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountName"].ToString();
            string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountPassword"].ToString();
            //System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            exchange = new exch.ExchangeService(exch.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
            {
                Credentials = new exch.WebCredentials(Name, Password, "EMEA"), -- EMEA - domain name
                Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
                //exchange.TraceEnabled = true;
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                //Timeout = 1000,
                EnableScpLookup = false
            };

            exch.Folder inbox = exch.Folder.Bind(exchange, exch.WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
            //Console.WriteLine("The folder name is " + inbox.DisplayName.ToString());
```

I am trying to implement the logic which is given in the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth#add-code-to-get-an-authentication-token

under the heading App-Only authentication

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.AcquireTokenForClient` and `OAuthCredentials` class. See [Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth) for an example.

Comment: I used the code mentioned in the above page and i am getting the below error while debugging

AADSTS1002016: You are using TLS version 1.0, 1.1 and/or 3DES cipher which are deprecated to improve the security posture of Azure AD.

Comment: You need to do something like the following first:
`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` to support SSL3 and TLS 1.1 / 1.2